# Skip duplicate rows in data while importing into mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, duplicates

I have more than 100k rows in csv file , I have to import into mysql database , the file containing more than 10000 duplicates and I have to skip when importing and i using ID as primary key and its auto increment so I can't use ignore data type in mysql.

columns are:
**"id", "ICD10Code", "ICD10Desc", "SNOMED", "SNOMEDSNOMEDDesc"**

id is an primary key 
remaining  4 columns have duplicate values

```
oCon = DBConnection.getConnection();
strSql = "Insert into batch (ICD10Code, ICD10Desc, SNOMED,SNOMEDDesc) values (?,?,?,?)";
oPrStmt = oCon.prepareStatement(strSql);
oReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFileName));
```

Comment: this are my column data

Comment: Oh... Sorry about that then.. I thought it was just spam..

Comment: @Kostas Mitsarakis i cant get u

Answer (score 1):

With only 100k rows of data, you should be able to keep track of the file contents in-memory. So, you could do the following:

- Create a `HashSet<String> uniqueRows` where you store the unique combinations of `{ICD10Code, ICD10Desc, SNOMED, SNOMEDDesc}` that you have already processed.
- For each row read from the CSV, concatenate the values of `{ICD10Code, ICD10Desc, SNOMED, SNOMEDDesc}` into a `String rowString` and check the value of `uniqueRows.contains(rowString)`.

  - If the row is already in the `Set`, skip it
  - If the row was not in the set, `INSERT` it into the DB and add it into the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a subset of columns that have to be unique, you can define a unique index on them, which will allow you to use IGNORE.